# How to determine in onPostExecute that activity is not paused now or destroyed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I start `AsyncTask` and put `Context` in constructor of the Task.

On `onPostExecute` I want to know is my activity active now and was not recreated. How it's better to do?

For this I can:

- create randomNumber in `onCreate` Activity and then put it in `Application` class;
- onPause/onDestroy set randomNumber to 0 and in `onResume` restore randomNumber;
- in `onPreExecute()` get randomNumber and in `onPostExecute` compare randomNumber with Application randomNumber.

May be I can use Context for making decision ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches to check if the activity is still there.

I usually create a `SkeletonActivity` with the following structure:

```
public class SkeletonActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private boolean paused = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        paused = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        paused = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        paused = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        paused = false;
    }
    public boolean isPaused() {
        return paused;
    }
}
```

Now let all your activities extend this `SkeletonActivity`. Finally change this Base Class to change the paused flag as you wish (For example update it in `onDestroy()`

---

Another way would be to have a Context instance inside your `SkeletonActivity`:

```
public class SkeletonActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mContext = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public boolean isPaused() {
        return mContext==null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first approach. How can I from `public class TaskGetOrderPay extends AsyncTask` get value from `isPaused()` ... ?

The second approach. In `doInBackground` I am using context, so setting `mContext = null;` can cause NullPoinException.

Comment: If it is an AsyncTask in a separate java file, then you should pass a reference to the SkeletonActivity. However, if it is inside your Activity, you can check `if(isPaused())`. In the second approach you should also check `if(isPaused())` before using the context. Btw, I use the first approach: a boolean flag is safer

Comment: Do you think, that reference to the Activity - is a good approach?

Comment: You will need some kind of a Reference. I prefer to handle it manually and pass it. If you want to be careful, use a static flag or a Singleton Class that saves the state.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this example. I do store the Context in the AsyncTask. During onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() I set it to null and during onCreate() I patch the Context to the currently running Activity. You can enhance that by setting "task = null" in onDestroy():

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    /* package */ MyActivity context;

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public MyAsyncTask(final MyActivity context) {
            super();

            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(/* ... */) {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(/* ... */) {
            if (context != null) {
                // ...
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute (/* ... */) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    /* package */ MyAsyncTask task;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        // ...

        Bundle bundleExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundleExtras != null) {
            task = (MyAsyncTask) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            if (task != null) {
                task.context = this;
                // ...
            } else {
                task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
                task.execute();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        if (task != null) {
            // ...

            task.context = null;
        }

        return task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It  will be help full for other guys.

if you press the home button or back button onStop() will called.so declare a variable inside the activity like

```
   boolean isActivityclosed=false;
```

During the onStop() method set value to true.

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isActivityclosed=true;

    }
```

now, at postExcecute method check the variable is true or not. if its true then your activity is in background.